# JQuery MouseOver/Out with FadeTo Impacts Click with FadeOut

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use JQuery to use a Bootstrap button, which is fixed to the left side of the browser.  It is designed to open a message box for people to chat.  The button needs to be at about half opacity, so it does not dominate that point on the browser.  I have written test code for the button, but the `mouseover` and `mouseout` are impacting the `click`.  So, with the `mouseover` and `mouseout` handlers, when I click the button, it fades away and comes right back.  If I comment out the two mouse event handlers, then the `fadeOut` works correctly.  Is there any way to fix this, so the `fadeOut` will work correctly?

```
$("#testButton").mouseover(function() {
    $("#testButton").fadeTo("fast", 1);
});
$("#testButton").mouseout(function() {
    $("#testButton").fadeTo("fast", 0.5);
});
$("#testButton").click(function() {
    $("#testButton").fadeOut("fast");
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use css for toggle opacity of your button like this

```
#testButton{ opacity :0.5};
#testButton:hover{ opacity :1};
```

and then javascript can be left only **click**

```
$("#testButton").click(function() {
    $("#testButton").fadeOut("fast");
});
```

hope this help